# Android widget listview with subitem

Tags: android, listview

I am making a widget with a listview, and I want to add subtitle to the widget. Currently, I can only show one line of text with this code:

Class that implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory:

```
  @Override
  public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {

  RemoteViews row = new RemoteViews(ctxt.getPackageName(), R.layout.row);
  String loadingData = "Loading Data";

  if(wmc != null){    
      try{
          String dayName = wmc.getDays().get(position).dayName;
          row.setTextViewText(android.R.id.text1, dayName);
      }
      catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
      }       
  }

  return row;
  }
```

My row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="6dip"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
/>
```

How do I insert a subtitle to the listview? I have tried something like this, but it does not work.

```
  @Override
  public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {

  RemoteViews row = new RemoteViews(ctxt.getPackageName(), R.layout.row);
  String loadingData = "Loading Data";

  if(wmc != null){    
      try{
          String dayName = wmc.getDays().get(position).dayName;
          row.setTextViewText(android.R.id.text1, dayName);
          row.setTextViewText(android.R.id.text2, dayName);
      }
      catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
      }       
  }

return row;
```

}

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    >
</TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your code: Look at the ids:

```
    row.setTextViewText(android.R.id.text1, dayName);
    row.setTextViewText(android.R.id.text2, dayName);
```

Here is the id from the row.xml that works:

```
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
```

Here are the ids from your second xml that doesn't work:

```
    android:id="@+id/text1"
```

and

```
    android:id="@+id/text2"
```

See it yet?

You are using the Android namespace ids.  Then in your second xml that doesn't work, you are using your app namespace for the ids.

Change your code to this (you'll need to make sure your importing the right `R` class):

```
    row.setTextViewText(R.id.text1, dayName);
    row.setTextViewText(R.id.text2, dayName);
```

Then use these ids in your xml:

```
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:id="@+id/text2"
```

and you should be all set.